# Include in where statment only if not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following :

how can i include a filter in my where statement only if it's not null?
i tried the following but i always get 0 records

```
public async Task<IList<UserRefDto>> GetUserRef(Dictionary<string, string> filter) {
var iod = 549; // a test user who has 2548 records in db
var favorites = filter.ContainsKey("fav") ? filter["fav"].ConvertToGuid(",") : null;
var histories = filter.ContainsKey("his") ? filter["his"].ConvertToGuid(",") : null;
var orders = filter.ContainsKey("ord") ? filter["ord"].ConvertToGuid(",") : null;
var result = await context.UserRefernces
               .Where(x =>
                      x.User_iod = iod 
                   && (favorites != null && favorites.Contains((Guid)x.FavId))
                   && (histories != null && histories.Contains((Guid)x.HistoryId))
                   && (orders != null && orders.Contains((Guid)x.OrderId))
                   )
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToListAsync()
               .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
}
```

**EDIT**
Note: If all keys have values then i got records back, only if one or more is null i got nothing back from db

Comment: Your (sub) condition has to be something like `(field == null || field.Contains(...))`.

Comment: why using ||? i only include it if not null?

Comment: @Maro isn't this supposed to be `==` instead of one `=`, `x.User_iod = iod`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your query with several `.Where()` statements, which will be added via an `AND` condition. But add the additional `.Where()` statements only when the values are present.

```
var query = context.UserRefernces
                   .Where(x => x.User_iod == iod);
if (favorites != null) {
    query = query.Where(x => favorites.Contains((Guid)x.FavId));
}
// same for "histories" and "orders"

var result = await query
           .AsNoTracking()
           .ToListAsync()
           .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `favorites != null &&` with `favorites == null ||` in your query as follows:

```
var result = await context.UserRefernces
               .Where(x => x.User_iod = iod 
                   && (favorites == null || favorites.Contains((Guid)x.FavId))
                   && (histories == null || histories.Contains((Guid)x.HistoryId))
                   && (orders == null || orders.Contains((Guid)x.OrderId)))
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToListAsync()
               .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
```

Now the query will work as expected.